write_videofile throws list index out of range - but works
I have a bunch of videos in a directory  1.mp4, 2.mp4 .... I am merging them into output_1_2.mp4.
The following code works, but ..
Its throwning an error that i cant seem to figure out.

Merging: videos/1.mp4 videos/2.mp4 videos/output_1_2.mp4
Length of clips list: 2
Moviepy - Building video videos/output_1_2.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in output_1_2TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
t:   0%|          | 0/499 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]MoviePy - Done.
Moviepy - Writing video videos/output_1_2.mp4
Error writing final clip: list index out of range

Again it works the files are merged, im just trying to understand the why
final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec='libx264')

is throwing an list index out of range error.
As the code works i can probably just ignore it.  This question is more out of curiosity.
Code
import os
import re

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips


def merge_videos_in_directory(directory):
    # Get a list of all files in the directory
    files = os.listdir(directory)

    # Filter out files that start with "output"
    files = [file for file in files if not file.startswith("output")]

    # Sort the files based on numeric part in the filename
    files.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))

    # Print the list of files for debugging
    print("Files in directory:", files)

    # Iterate through the files in pairs
    for i in range(0, len(files), 2):
        # Check if there are at least two files remaining
        if i + 1 < len(files):
            # Get the paths of the two videos to merge
            video1_path = os.path.join(directory, files[i])
            video2_path = os.path.join(directory, files[i + 1])

            # Create the output file name
            output_name = f"output_{files[i][:-4]}_{files[i + 1][:-4]}.mp4"
            output_path = os.path.join(directory, output_name)

            # Merge the two videos
            print("Merging:", video1_path, video2_path, output_path)
            try:
                merge_videos(video1_path, video2_path, output_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error merging videos:", e)


def merge_videos(video1_path, video2_path, output_path):
    # Load the video clips
    video1 = VideoFileClip(video1_path)
    video2 = VideoFileClip(video2_path)

    # Print the lengths of the clips list for debugging
    print("Length of clips list:", len([video1, video2]))

    # Concatenate the video clips
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([video1, video2])

    try:
        # Write the final clip to a file
        final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec='libx264')  # exception thrown here.

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any errors
        print("Error writing final clip:", e)
        # Close the clips if an error occurs
        final_clip.close()
        video1.close()
        video2.close()
    finally:
        # Close the clips
        final_clip.close()
        video1.close()
        video2.close()


# Example usage:
videos_dir = "videos/"
merge_videos_in_directory(videos_dir)

I am wondering if it may just be related to Duration floating point round-off causes "IndexError: list index out of range" in write_videofile

Based on a similar user reported bug here it could also be caused if one of the videos you are joining together has a malformed audio track. Have you verified that the new merged video has the complete expected audio track and does not go silent in the middle?

the videos have no audio (just testing).  they all appear to merge fine.
